# Displaying future dates in ionic ion-datetime field

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to create an ion-datetime input field in an ionic 4 application, but the problem is that the future years are not showing! instead, it's showing only the current and past dates.
But since it is a "To Do" form I want the user to choose only the current date or future dates. So how can I solve this problem?

These are my "ion-datetime" fields:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label>Start Time</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime 
    pickerFormat="D M YYYY h m A" 
    displayFormat="YYYY MMMM DD HH mm"
     [(ngModel)]="StartTime">
    </ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>End Time</ion-label>
    <ion-datetime 
    pickerFormat="D M YYYY h m A" 
    displayFormat="YYYY MMMM DD HH mm"
    [(ngModel)]="EndTime">
    </ion-datetime>
  </ion-item>
```

These are the dates showing:

[image: output of ion-datetime]

If you need any extra information to help you solve my problem please ask me to do so.

Comment: [yearValues]="[2022, 2023, 2024]" u can use this to select years, and for the end time selector, use [min]="start_date.value", and on the start time selector put #start_date and [min]="min_start_time" and min_start_time u declare in ts file and it will be equal new Date().toISOString(); so in this way the  value that u choose in the first date will force the second selector to start from that point...

Answer (score 0):

strong textYou can provide max or min component propeties, somethingk like:

```
<"ion-datetime min="1994-03-14" max="2099-12-09" ></ion-datetime">
```

Dynamic min and Max Values:

TS:

```
minYear = '2021';
maxYear = '2025-10-31'; // based on your calculations;
```

HTML:

```
<"ion-datetime [min]="minYear" [max]="maxYear" ></ion-datetime">
```

Comment: the thing is I want to put dynamic min and max based on the current date, so how can I do so?

Comment: You can use `[min]="YourMinVariable"`  `[max]="yourMaxVariable"` .

Comment: my max date is in the past, say like 1999. still if I click on picker, it will show today's date in the picker as default.

How to set initial date?

I have tried setting ngModel to the picker, it shows the past date in the input field. the problem is only when I click open the picker, it always show todays date